# TvOS: Using CollectionViewCells as a Button

Tags: swift, tvos

I am new to all of this, so please excuse if there is an obvious answer to my question.

I have a native tvOS application which incorporates a CollectionViewController very similar to that, which Apple uses in their [UIKitCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Introduction/Intro.html).

I have set everything up programmatically, as I am not looking for a storyboard based answer. By default a user can interact with the cell, that is in focus, but how exactly would I achieve that by clicking a cell you are forwarded to a different view controller. I know how to do this with a Button and an IBAction, but I would like the cell to act as a button in this case, so how should I do this?

Thank you for your answers!

Regards Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using UICollectionViewDelegate collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: i guess you can performSegue

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: